# What is a God Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a Word conforms to a special rule, I call it God Word™.
Use the following examples to find the rule.

| God Words™ | Not God Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| OFF | OPIUM |
| CLIP | RELAXED |
| WEATHER | ADORNED |
| RESIGN | SUNRISE |
| FAST | FLOORED |
| DUST | BEGONE |
| STONE | CORNICE |
| CONTINUE | ANTIDOTE |
| SCREEN | EARSHOT |

This satisfies the series' in-built assumption that every word can be independently tested for being a God Word. These are not the only examples of God Word. Many more, but a limited finite number exist.

Comment: Interesting that you specify that a limited finite number exist... but technically that would be true of any Word series ;)

Comment: @frabjrew: Yeah, that hint made it easy to find the answer.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A God Word™ is a word that...

> can act as its own opposite (i.e., an [auto-antonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym) or contranym). Also called a [*Janus word*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/words-own-opposites), named after the Roman god [Janus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janus) who had two faces that looked in opposite directions. Some are listed in [this Mental Floss article](http://mentalfloss.com/article/57032/25-words-are-their-own-opposites) as well as the links above:
>
>  **Off**: activated (set off) or deactivated (turned off).
>  **Clip**: attach or cut off.
>  **Weather**: withstand (weather a storm) or wear away.
>  **Resign**: quit or sign up again.
>  **Fast**: stay in place (hold fast) or move quickly.
>  **Dust**: remove dust from or add dust to.
>  **Stone**: remove the stone from (as in fruit) or throw stones at.
>  **Continue**: keep doing something or (legally speaking) stop a proceeding (as in a continuance).
>  **Screen**: show (as in a movie) or conceal.

Comment: Just write the reason why I call them God Words and you will get the coveted checkmark. :-)

Comment: @Sid: I thought I did. Is it not related to the Roman god these words are named after?

Comment: Oh. Oops. My mistake. I didn't see that you had mentioned it.

Comment: @sid, is that the original idea you had for stone?

Comment: This is the sort of puzzle that cleaves me.